# Converting CLC local urban atlas vector files to raster

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdal-rasterize

I am try to convert vector files to raster files from the Corine land use data set which provides vector files in their urban atlas. As per:
https://land.copernicus.eu/local/urban-atlas

For example, I downloaded the files for Wien from here:
https://land.copernicus.eu/local/urban-atlas/urban-atlas-2012?tab=download

In particular, I am interested in rasterizing the field CODE2012, which provides the integer code for the land classification (ITEM2012 and OBJECTID could possibly be an option but the most direct route is CODE2012).

I tried using the QGIS->Raster->Conversion->Rasterize which uses GDAL but I keep getting empty geotiffs or errors. I have also tried manually with `gdal_rasterize` which is what QGIS uses:

```
gdal_rasterize -l AT001L3_WIEN_UA2012_Boundary -a Pop2012 -ts 1.0 1.0 -a_nodata 0.0 -te 1843982.5417865077 6166351.096614478 1848539.9284615591 6169446.97652822 -ot Float32 -of GTiff ./AT001L3_WIEN_013/Data/AT001L3_WIEN_013.gpkg output.tif
```

I have tried many different versions of the above, that is just for an example.

I have looked at vector to raster conversion posts and understand the concept.

How do I get this particular data set conversion working?

Answer (score 1):

To save some time used the ArcGIS MapServer option in QGIS

```
https://image.discomap.eea.europa.eu/arcgis/rest/services/UrbanAtlas/UA_UrbanAtlas_2012/MapServer
```

[image]

[image]